# Cannot return a member field that is a map of unique_ptr in c++

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, unordered-map

I have a class that looks like this

```
class MyCalss
{
public:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Entity>> getMyMap() const;

private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Entity>> m_myMap;
}
```

In the implementation, I simple return m_myMap in getMyMap() like so,

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Entity>> MyClass::getMyMap() const
{
    return m_myMap;
}
```

How come this is not allowed? I get a bunch of compilation error doing this.

Comment: is there a reason you want to use unique_ptr there instead of the "Entity"? i cannot imagine one.

Comment: Read the lines of the compilation errors you didn't bother posting... *closely*. It will tell you the copy ctor of the map template expansion you're using has been deleted. Considering the map contains un-copyable values, that shouldn't come as a surprise.

Comment: Linked answer is for `std::vector`, but the same thing happens with any standard container.

Comment: @mikk Polymorphism?

Answer (score 1):

Your getter is trying to return a copy of `m_myMap`, but the copy constructor of `std::unique_ptr<Entity>` is deleted: it means that a `std::unique_ptr` cannot be copied by definition, being unique.

Probably you should return a const reference to `m_myMap` instead of a copy, declaring your getter as:

```
const std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Entity>>& getMyMap() const;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because a `std::unique_ptr` cannot be copied.

`std::unique_ptr` is a smart pointer that owns and manages another object through a pointer and disposes of that object when the `std::unique_ptr` goes out of scope.

Since you return a copy of `m_myMap`, the copy constructor of `std::unordered_map` constructs a container with a copy of its contents, and fails to do so since `std::unique_ptr` cannot be copied.

Comment: This answer would be better if it pointed out that this property is usually transitive. A standard container of `unique_ptr`s is also not copyable.

Comment: @Jamit that's actually purpose of scoped_ptr which didn't make it into standard. Unique_ptr ensures that object would be disposed and neither copied nor left dangling pointers